# Cannot see 5GHz networks and have terrible WiFi range, used to work in Win10

Tags: networking, wireless, intel-wireless, iwlwifi

I have the Intel 7260 chip that worked well for both 2.4 and 5 GHz networks when I ran Win10. I installed Ubuntu a few days ago and the range of the WiFi is terrible, and I cannot see any 5GHz networks at all.

Since I installed Ubuntu a few days ago I should reasonably have the newest kernel, or am I wrong? I think I have the newest firmware as well.

```
$ uname -r
4.10.0-38-generic

$ modinfo iwlwifi | grep 7260
firmware: iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode

$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 
[8086:08b2] (rev 73)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless-N 7260 [8086:4262]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Does anyone have a solution? I am very new to Linux and appreciate all help I can get. Google hasn't been very helpful.

Comment: Please edit to include results for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net`

Comment: Okey! I have done that now.

Answer (score 1):

First we will backup the existing modules

```
sudo mv /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko.bak
sudo mv /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko.bak
```

Then we can install some packages to get the source code and compile

```
sudo apt-get install git built essential
```

```
git clone https://github.com/jeremyb31/intel-4.10.git
```

```
cd intel-4.10/iwlwifi
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) clean
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules
sudo cp iwlwifi.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
sudo cp mvm/iwlmvm.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko
```

Then we disable wireless power management

```
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
```

Reboot

I would also send an email to ilw@linux.intel.com explaining about this chipset being identified in the linux kernel as a non dual band chipset, send the lspci results that you added to the question

If this works, commands after a kernel update do

```
cd intel-4.10/iwlwifi
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) clean
make -C /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build M=$(pwd) modules
sudo cp iwlwifi.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
sudo cp mvm/iwlmvm.ko /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/mvm/iwlmvm.ko
```

And then reboot for it to work in the new kernel

Comment: Hello. I have been busy with school and other things so I haven't had time to test this yet.


I did everything as you said with the exception of adding intel/ before the iwlwifi directory, because when I did exactly as you said it couldn't find the folder.


However, now my built in WiFi-chip doesn't show up when searching for connections (I am currently using a cheap external WiFi-chip).  When i run lspci the row that said "Kernel driver in use" has disappeared. Is there a next step? Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Hello again!  

Maybe you said this and I misunderstood you but I updated the kernel via some googling, and now I got my built-in Wifi-chip back in the connections menu. I still cannot see 5GHz networks, but I will send that email that you recommended and maybe someday I will be able to find 5GHz networks!  

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in UEFI/BIOS settings and see if the older kernel works